# Underscore 'after' function

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have code similar to this

```
(function(exports, $, Backbone, document){
    "use strict";

    var modals = {
        "Alerts.alert_delete" : (function() {
            var self = this;    
            return {
                template : {
                    count : this.collection.length,
                    models : this.collection.models
                },
                events : {
                    "click .confirm" : function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var modal = this,
                            finished = _.after(modal.collection.length, self.reDraw);

                        // Models are succesfully delete, but finished is not completed 
                        this.collection.each(function(model) {
                            modal.collection.sync('delete', model, { success : finished });
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
        })
    };

    exports.app.modal = function(name, context) {
        return modals[name].call(context);
    };
}(this, jQuery, Backbone, document));
```

Please ignore the abstraction, this is to allow me to use one generic view for all my modals whilst keeping unique logic abstracted. I am at a loss as to why the `_.after` function is not completing when it has been called the correct number of times. `self` in this instance is a reference to the parent view.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: You're sure that it's actually being called the correct number of times?  If you replace `finished` with `function() { console.log('hello'); }` you see the `model.collection.length` number of hellos?

Comment: Actually, the deferred object on delete requests doesn't seem to get resolved on success. Running a jQuery.complete on the object seems to be the only way to use it in Chrome. @CallebJoshua the point is it is only ever run once, that is what _.after does